# I would like to search for a word in google using javascript

Tags: javascript

window.open("https://www.google.com/#q="+functionText());

//the function contains a text that I want to search on google

//I tried a lot and seems there is something I miss can you help please?

}

Answer (score 1):

That would work. Make sure the text from the function is encoded.

```
encodeURIComponent(text);
```

Comment: that is the problem , it only opens the link not the text added on it it only shows https://www.google.com/#q= only

Comment: Make sure the function returns the text.